# SQL CONVERT function working in SQL Server but not in application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012

I have a following code:

```
…
var sqlCom =
            new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 …,CONVERT(date,dtetme) AS dtetme… FROM class c WHERE id=@id;", sqlCon);
…

        try
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
                    rslt[i] = sdr.GetValue(i).ToString();
        }
```

The column `dtetme` is of type `smalldatetime` in my *SQL Server 2012* database. I only want to extract date from it so that’s why I am using `CONVERT(date,dtetme)` function. When run on SQL server, it returns only the date as expected, but in the application it is returning it with a default timestamp attached. I don’t want like this: `9/19/2013 12:00:00 AM`.

Any idea why it is working in SQL Server and not in my application?

Comment: Good god, punctuation please. Use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date is a date is a date. Not a string. You should read it *as a date*, and then format it as you choose afterwards. To the database, a date is just a number - it has no notion of format. So:

```
var when = sdr.GetDateTime(i);
// now format when
```

Comment: Thankyou for pointing in the right direction, as i didnt wanted to change the loop-code so got it working through a change in the query `CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dtetme)`.

Answer (score 0):

Its is returned as `DateTime` object. In .Net `DateTime` is not just Date, it also has a Time part, which is set to 12:00 AM when not provided.

You should save your result in `DateTime` type object using `DateReader.GetDateTime` and then you can format it according to your need.

You may see : [Custom DateTime formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    DateTime temp = sdr.GetDateTime(i);
    rslt[i] = temp.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to answer your question is that your value is represented as date type not as string. A date in sql sever is represented as Aaron wrote in comment.

This mean that you need to format it using some pattern. IN that pattern you say what part of time you need.

It appear that in your RDBMS, by default i used pattern that only prints day month and year. In your app from other hand is pattern `dd/MM/YY hh:mm:ss tt`

Just format it to be as you expect.

An example

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`

Comment: A datetime in SQL Server is represented internally as two integers: (a) the number of days offset from 1900-01-01 and (b) the number of .33 millisecond increments since midnight. It has nothing to do with epoch (1970-01-01) - I think you are confusing this with Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is .Net does not have a Date data type only DateTime. You can use `dtetme.ToString("d")` if you wish to display a short date.

See all the ToString options here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx